# Coldfusion ORM 9.0.1 - Error while resolving relationship

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I got this example from the adobe coldfusion documentation, some of the names are changed but everything else is the same, unless I am just so frustrated that I have missed a letter.

user.cfc:

```
/**
 *@persistent
 */
component 
{
    property name="id" fieldtype="id" generator="native";
    property name="userName" type="string" length="100";

    property name="Credential" fieldtype="one-to-one" cfc="model.user.credentials";
}
```

credentials.cfc:

```
/**
*@persistent
*/
component 
{
    property  name="id" fieldtype="id" generator="foreign" params="{property='userinfo'}";
    property name="userinfo" fieldtype="one-to-one" cfc="model.user.user" constrained="true";
    property name="passwordHash" type="string";
}
```

no matter how I word it, after searching many sites, I still get a error of:
Error while resolving the relationship Credential in cfc user. Check the column mapping for this property.

I have checked that both cfcs are accessible by coldfusion by removing the one-to-one properties and the tables have been created successfully.

I am using SQL Server 2008 with Coldfusion 9.0.1 under Apache 2.2 web server.

I am new to ORM and Hibernate but have successfully created different types of relationships and will confess to a less then expert level of coldfusion.

Thanks, this is really bothering me as this came directly from the coldfusion documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a mapping for model?

If not, add one, or you could try:

```
property name="Credential" fieldtype="one-to-one" cfc="credentials";
```

Comment: well, i don't have a mapping for model, model.user is the directory structure from the base directory, I will try giving model a mapping and see what happens.

Comment: when I add the mapping, same error, when I use cfc="credentials" (same in both cfcs) same error

Comment: I give credit for this answer here, as his advice did led me to the answer i was looking for. For some reason my mapping to model didn't work as expected, so I made a mapping to models, adjusted the cfcs to point at models.user.etc, and it worked. Now a cookie to the person that tells me why.